# How to integrate JBoss 7.4.10.GA (domain.xml or other configurations) to work with IBM MQ hosted on another server?

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq, message-queue

Can you help with the IBM MQ integration with JBoss. Currently the resources archive which I am providing is not being picked up by JBoss and I am getting error as below:
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.ra."wmq.jmsra""],

I have put this rar file in JBoss standalone/deployments and also in the modules but nothing helps.

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="MyResourceAdapter">
                    <archive>
                        wmq.jmsra.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/ComCF" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MyConnectionFactory">
                            <config-property name="channel"></config-property>
                            <config-property name="hostName"></config-property>
                            <config-property name="PortNumber"></config-property>
                            <config-property name="queueManager"></config-property>
                            <config-property name="ServerName"></config-property>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                    <admin-objects>
                        <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/exported/Com" pool-name="ComQueue">
                            <config-property name="baseQueueName">Com</config-property>
                            <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName"></config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                    </admin-objects>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```